# Linking cells in excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to link two cell in excel sheet. so i can edit cell values from both side.

for example:

I have two sheets in my excel.
sheet01 sheet02

A1 cell of sheet01 is connected with A1 cell of sheet02.

I can edit sheet01 cell and display value in sheet02
but sheet02 cell have =sheet01!A1

now i want a way to edit sheet02 A1 cell that's display data in A1 cell of sheet01.

simply, Both side communication for two linked cell in excel.

Comment: You will want to use VBA in a worksheet change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for the "Sheet1" object :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also copy this code to the "Sheet2" object. You only have to change the *Sheets("Sheet2")* part into *Sheets("Sheet1")*.

Comment: No reason to use intersect if you are only checking against one cell, just check if the addresses are the same (minutely faster than calling Intersect, though realistically a difference you'd never notice)

Comment: Just thinking ahead :-)